# Why is the comparison operator not finding matches in Google App Script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, comparison-operators

I have a small function that takes a string (strOrder = 658492-1), splits it into just the first part before the '-' and compares it to values in a cell in a spreadsheet (which is also split).  If it is a match, it should add the spreadsheet row to an array.  Unfortunately, it is not finding any matches, but even the log shows they are the same.  Help!

```
  function getLinks2(strOrder) {
  var mLinks = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Main');
  var data = mLinks.getDataRange().getValues();
  var boxOrder = '';
  var shortOrder = '';
  var sOrder = '';
  var arrLinks = [];

  data.shift();

  strOrder = strOrder.replace(/\s/g, "");
  var oTemp = strOrder.split('-');
  boxOrder = oTemp[0];

  Logger.log('boxOrder:x' + boxOrder + 'x');

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    shortOrder = data[i][4].toString();
    shortOrder = shortOrder.replace(/\s/g, "");
    var soTemp = shortOrder.split('-');
    sOrder = soTemp[0];

    Logger.log('sOrder:x' + sOrder + 'x');

    if (boxOrder == sOrder) {
      Logger.log('match');
      arrLinks.push(data[i]);
      //the item matches the order id
    } else {
      //item does not match the order id
    } // end if order id matches
  } // end for loop through data
  return arrLinks;
} // end function getLinks2
```

Here are the Log results:

```
boxOrder:x685492x
sOrder:x658492x
sOrder:x658492x
sOrder:x658492x
sOrder:x699249x
sOrder:x698406x
```

(I used the 'x' around the strings to check if there were extra spaces.)

What am I missing?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: There is no match in your log print out.  Did you transpose a number?  Like the second and third number, for testing.  But add a couple more log statements:  `Logger.log(boxOrder == sOrder);Logger.log(boxOrder === sOrder);`  Put those log statements before the `if` test.  Test with triple equal signs also.

Comment: Yes, the number is transposed in my test function!  I had just looked at it too long sorting out something else.  Thanks for your help!